# Is this possible in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

my domain: `www.teste.com.br`

my folder (not exists): `diretory`

my virtual url: `www.teste.com.br/diretory`

my folder (exists): `diretory2/dir/index.php`

When accessing `www.teste.com.br/diretory` view the contents of `diretory2/dir/index.php`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, to rewrite one URL to the other:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^diretory$ /diretory2/dir/index.php [L]
```

If `/diretory` is "virtual" then it's just a URL. It's not really a "folder".

In order to rewrite all files within the first directory to the corresponding file (with the same name) in the other directory then add the following `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^diretory/(.*)$ diretory2/dir/$1 [L]
```

The `QSA` is not required here since the query string on the requested URL will be automatically be copied across to the target.

Comment: try....

RewriteRule ^diretory\/(.*)$ diretory2/dir/$1 [QSA,L]

it works
tks
Marco

Comment: Ah ok, that rule is required in order to copy _all_ URLs within that virtual directory. The `QSA` flag is not required in this instance unless you are modifying the substitution to include a query string. You also don't need to backslash escape the slash in the `RewriteRule` pattern. I've updated my answer to include your comment. (If the answer helped resolve your problem then you can mark it as "accepted" to remove it from the unanswered question queue. You can also upvote it - once you have enough reputation - if you found it helpful.)